# Posso abrir o VS2017 com um usuário diferente daquele colocado na instalação?

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server, active-directory

Posso abrir o VS2017 com um usuário diferente daquele colocado na instalação? Porque estou tentando entrar com um novo usuário que me foi dado na empresa. Esse novo usuário é o meu usuário no AD e com ele eu acesso o TFS já que com o usuário atual(usuário MicroSoft usado na instalação do TFS). O note que trampo é o meu particular e não o dá empresa, por isso dois usuário diferentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando o Visual Studio Pro? Se sim, não existe a necessidade de conectar com a sua conta da Microsoft no Visual Studio, ele permite que você utilize todas as funcionalidades do VS sem a necessidade de autenticação.

Porem caso você necessite realizar a autenticação para utilizar diversas contas da Microsoft, você pode seguir o passo a passo estipulado no site da Microsoft : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/dn872465.aspx

Caso você esteja utilizando o Visual Studio Community é necessário a autenticação e você pode utilizar apenas 1 conta de usuário por licença.

Comment: Anderson, consegui. Me desloguei do VS2017 Enterprise. O problema estava exatamente aí. Não me loguei com outro usuário ainda, mas não sei se posso. A questão de logar com outro usuário era poder me conectar ao TFS, já que com o usuário que estava logado estava sem permissão. Mas ao deslogar consegui me conectar ao TFS e por isso nem tentei me logar com outro usuário.